# working with htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite the following url:

`index.php/variable` where variable can be any name such about,contact, etc.

to
`page/variable or page/variable/` where variable can be any non case-sensitive character.

Essentially the user would access `page/variable` or `page/variable/` which would rewrite the url of the `index.php/variable`

I have tried the following:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)/$ /index.php/$1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

but that has not been successful.

Comment: In theory these rules should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one rule for both actions:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php/$1 [NC,L]
```

This will internally redirect a url ending with or without a slash to "/index.php/$1"

Comment: would it also be possible to make a request url rewrite so that when somone type index.php/about for instance it translate to page/about